# How can I make alternate fragments drop (or make them black) based on a checkerboard texture?

Tags: unity, fragment-shader

How can I make alternate fragments drop(or make them black) based on a checkerboard texture in a Unity fragment shader?

I am using forward path rendering in my shader passes for lighting and shadows for every object in the scene.

Now,I need a shader (or something) that drops alternate pixels from the overall screen space after everything is rendered. How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can check the fragment coordinates (assuming they're integers going from (0,0) to (width, height)) and if both are even or both are odd keep the fragment, otherwise reject it. (Or the reverse if you prefer.)

In pseudocode it would look like this:

```
bool rowIsEven = (fragCoord.x % 2) == 0;
bool colIsEven = (fragCoord.y % 2) == 0;
if (rowIsEven == colIsEven)
{
    // keep the fragment
}
else
{
    // discard the fragment
}
```

If your coordinates are normalized, then you can multiply them by the width and height before checking the result. You'll need to pass the width and height in as a uniform, probably.

Comment: In Unity ShaderLab specifically, you can do this with the [VPOS semantic as described here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ShaderSemantics.html) (on shader model 3.0 plus), or manually by passing the projected position in from the vertex shader and scaling it with the `_ScreenParams` [built-in uniform variable](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-UnityShaderVariables.html). Also note you can save one modulo operation by just adding the row & column first and taking the parity of the result (even + even / odd + odd both make an even)

Answer (score 0):

Writing up my 2019 comment as an answer, since the advice never got incorporated into the existing answer.

You can apply these modifications to a basic Unity shader to accomplish this:

1. Use `#pragma target 3.0` to enable the use of the `VPOS` semantic to get the pixel coordinates of the fragment being drawn inside the fragment shader.
2. Move your `SV_POSITION` out of the `v2f` structure and into an `out` parameter of your vertex shader instead. (Otherwise having both `SV_POSITION` and `VPOS` as inputs to the fragment shader causes a conflict)

   ```
   struct v2f
   {
       float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
   };

   v2f vert (appdata v, out float4 outpos : SV_POSITION)
   {
       v2f o;
       outpos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
       o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);    
       return o;
   }
   ```
3. Add `VPOS` to your fragment shader, and use it to `clip()` out the unwanted fragments.

   ```
   fixed4 frag (v2f i, UNITY_VPOS_TYPE screenPos : VPOS) : SV_Target
   {
       // Make a number that alternates even-odd on adjacent pixels.
       // (This is the Manhattan distance from (0, 0) to this pixel)
       float manhattan = screepPos.x + screenPos.y;

       // 0 for even, 1 for odd.
       float parity = manhattan % 2;

       // Discard all the even ones.
       clip(parity - 0.5);
       // (Or clip(-parity ) to discard odd ones.

       // Other fragment shader content here...
   }
   ```